# ViewModel- not updating on inherited Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have a viewmodel `ProductionViewModel` that extends a more general `EntityViewModelBase<T>` which again extends the mmvm-light's `ViewModelBase` (that derives from ObservableObject).

When calling this viewmodel I set the underlying data via it's method `SetItem(production)`

```
ProductionViewModel pview = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ProductionViewModel>();
pview.SetItem((Models.Production) msg.Model);
ViewContent = pview;
```

related XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="ProductionViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ProductionViewModel}">
            <views:ProductionView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<!-- then later -->
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewContent}"/>
```

this is the (simplified) ViewModel:

```
public class ProductionViewModel : EntityViewModelBase<Production>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }  // shall be in BaseClass

    public ProductionViewModel() {}

    public void SetItem(Production model) // shall be in BaseClass
    {
        Item = model;
    }

    // a subViewModel
    public ArtistgroupListViewModel ArtistgroupListViewModel
    {
        get
        {          // BREAKPOINT 1
            ArtistgroupListViewModel vm = new ArtistgroupListViewModel();
            //vm.SetArtistgroups(Artistgroups); // that's the goal
            vm.SetTestText(Item.Label); // that's for debugging only
            return vm;
        }
    }

    //EDIT: added all Properties that live here, but should not be related:
    public string LastModified => Item.LastModified.ToShortDateString() + " " + Item.LastModified.ToShortTimeString();

    public Workgroup Workgroup => (Workgroup) Task.Run(() => Store.FindItemByIdAsync(typeof(Workgroup), Item.Workgroup.Id)).Result;

    public List<BaseModel> Artistgroups => Task.Run(() => Store.QueryAsync(typeof(Artistgroup), new Filter(Item.Artistgroups.Ids))).Result;
}
```

The relevant Parts of `EntityViewModelBase`:

```
public abstract class EntityViewModelBase<T> : ViewModelBase
    where T : BaseModel
{
    //public T Item { get; set; }

    public EntityViewModelBase()
    {
       // this gets called 
    }

    //public void SetItem(T currentItem)
    //{                                   // BREAKPOINT 2
    //    Item = currentItem;
    //}
}
```

Then in SubViewModel `ArtistgroupListViewModel` I just set that TestText

```
    public string Test { get; set; } = "Test";
    public void SetTestText(string txt)
    {
        Test = txt;
    }
```

and show it in the fitting View.xaml

In this configuration *all is good*, and TestText get's updated in the View.

**But** I actually wanted to move

```
public T Item { get; set; }

public void SetItem(Production model)
{                                     // BREAKPOINT 2
    Item = model;
}
```

from ProductionViewModel to the EntityViewModelBase (as you can see, the commented Versions already living there).
But when I do this, *and switch between productions* - which calls `SetItem()` on the ProductionViewModel - the Text doesn't update anymore.

Symptoms:

- Breakpoint 2 gets hit, the Production itself get's updated in ProductionView.xaml
- Breakpoint 1 (SetTestText) *doesn't* get hit on change, therefore the TestText doesn't update.
- same behaviour if I only move either the property `Item` or the method `SetItem()` to EntityViewModelBase

**So the questions are:**
Is there a way I can move those two? And if not, why would I have to keep them in the extending class? This would contradict my understanding of extending classes. Is it a matter of implementing INotifyPropertyChanged? (Though I also tried that via Fody)

All packages at there latest version, .Net 4.6.

*EDITS:*

The getter of ArtistgroupListViewModel is called via a binding in xaml like so:

```
<local:ArtistgroupListView DataContext="{Binding Path=ArtistgroupListViewModel, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
```

Comment: Is the getter of the _ArtistgroupListViewModel_ property normally called by a binding, or is it supposed to be called due to some of your code accessing this property? Is some of your code perhaps reflecting on the properties of the ProductionViewModel (perhaps somewhere in a value converter)? Just moving the property to the base class should not change the behavior, unless somewhere something is specifically reflecting (or alike) upon members of the ProductionViewModel type, or you do some funky member hiding in ProductionViewModel perhaps. Without knowing the code it is hard to tell...

Comment: thanks for the reply - quick answer: I don't think anything of what you asked is the case, but I'll investigate now every point!

Comment: _"Is some of your code perhaps reflecting on the properties of the ProductionViewModel (perhaps somewhere in a value converter)?"_ kinda yes: There are additional Properties in ProductionViewModel which are bound to XAML (they update in every version) and there are `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`s involved (on properties of EntityViewModelBase). I've added all properties to the question's code

Comment: BooleanToVisibilityConverter doesn't look like a suspect. Where is this XAML code for `<local:ArtistgroupListView DataContext ... />` defined? Is it inside a data template? Is the data template associated with a particular type, or is an data/item template selector involved?

Comment: This xaml lives in a simple UserControl `ProductionView.xaml`as it is, bound to ProductionViewModel.cs via mvvmlight's Service Locator. A data template selector is only involved for the top level. Now included at the top of the question!

Comment: Hmm, nothing jumps out to me. The code examples you added to your question all look unsuspicious. :-(

Comment: that's my problem then... thanks for taking your time!

Comment: after more investigation I guess it might have to do with the way mvvmlight's ViewModelLocator works. It seems like those extending classes are not "connected" somehow. Because the construction works in another case where I don't get the viewModel via ViewModelLocator

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution/the reason for my problem:

It was indeed the mvvm-light ViewModelLocator or the fact that it uses *one* instance of the ViewModel.

So I only changed in the main parent VieModel:

```
ProductionViewModel pview = new ProductionViewModel(); // no more ServiceLocator...
pview.SetItem((Models.Production) msg.Model);
ViewContent = pview;
```